# UIAlertView after exiting UIPickerView as inputView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uipickerview, uicontrolevents

Hi I have a textfield to which I have assigned a UIPickerView as inputView. The UIPickerView has a method called using addTarget:action:forControlEvent: which I want to bring up an alertView to ask the user if this change is what they want.

Currently, I have the main view of the view controller as a UIControl, so when the background is tapped during editing I call [self.view endEditing:YES];

I want to bring up a UIAlertView when I end editing my textfield, I am playing with the control event. UIControlEventValueChanged doesn't work well because it brings up an alert view every time the wheel is spun and released, not only on exit. The other control events like UIControlEventDidEndEditing/OnExit don't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Even though the UIControlEventValueChanged worked on its own, I needed to hook up my textfield to my action method through interface builder. For some reason it did not work through code with the UIPickerView.